# The meaning of USFDA (in cosmetics)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, bond, precipitation

The full meaning of USFDA base on the definition of cosmetic meaning and production

Comment: Aside of the particular answer below, the great reference for acronyms is https://www.acronymfinder.com

Answer (score 1):

One likely possible meaning of USFDA is [United States Food and Drug Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USFDA), since

> «The United States Food and Drug Administration (FDA or USFDA) is a federal agency of the Department of Health and Human Services. The FDA is responsible for protecting and promoting public health through the control and supervision of food safety, tobacco products, dietary supplements, prescription and over-the-counter pharmaceutical drugs (medications), vaccines, biopharmaceuticals, blood transfusions, medical devices, electromagnetic radiation emitting devices (ERED), ***cosmetics***, animal foods & feed and veterinary products.»
>
> source: Wikipedia (emphasis added ny mine)